# Is it possible to install gns3?

Tags: software-installation

I would like to install gns3 on my Raspberry Pi and wonder if it is possible? 
I can not find a distribution that supports it, but wonder if anyone has done this or knows a link to a site or group who has done it. My search on Google didn't give much help.

Answer (score 1):

GNS3 shows in the raspbian repo, but dynamips seems to be missing. A quick google search indicates that there are [some issues due to the ARM architecture of the RPi](http://forum.gns3.net/topic7453.html) affecting performance. Raspbian seems to lack libpcap-devel which is a [dependency for compiling from source](https://github.com/GNS3/dynamips). Somebody on the RPi forum has indicated [success with dynamips](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=96735).

Comment: "libpcap-devel" doesn't sound like a package name from a debian-based distro. I presume the debian/raspbian equivilent is libpcap-dev which does exist in raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. Install Ubuntu-mate to be able to install GNS3. Below you will find a reference link created by Jason C. Neumann who explains how you can run routers using dynamips or an operating system using qemu.

Reference Link:
https://www.gns3.com/discussions/how-to-install-gns3-1-3-7-on-the